# Invalid function warning in Emacs

Tags: emacs, warnings

I wanted to get rid of that automatic "splash screen" that Emacs visits (called *GNU Emacs*). I added the following line to my .emacs file:

(add-hook 'after-init-hook '(kill-buffer "*GNU Emacs*"))

Well, it works, but I get the following warning message in the echo area:

"Invalid function: (kill-buffer "*GNU Emacs*")

I don't see what's invalid. Anyone know?

Thanks,
P.S. I'm sure a better approach would be to get Emacs to just not visit the *GNU Emacs* in the first place, but I haven't figured out how to do that (maybe something in the default.el file?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Take a look at the variable `inhibit-startup-screen`.

   ```
   (setq inhibit-startup-screen t)
   ```
2. The function `add-hook` expects a function as its second argument; `'(kill-buffer ...)` evaluates to a list, which is not a function.  One way to turn it into a function is to use the `lambda` operator:

   ```
   (add-hook 'after-init-hook (lambda () (kill-buffer "GNU Emacs")))
   ```

Comment: Yes, solution 1 fits the task exactly. It reminds me of Apple's slogan, "There's an App for that." In Emacs, it's "There's a variable for that!" Solution 2 is something I'll have to educate myself so more on.

Answer (score 0):

`(setq inhibit-default-init 1)` is one way to do it.  Didn't it work for you?

Comment: I suppose this would work, but isn't it overkill (certainly compared to inhibit-startup-screen)